# How to align buttons no matter size of different content in Material-UI Accordion?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to add a button to my Accordion so that it can be used to navigate to another page where the recipe will be rendered. The issue is each dish has a different length name so the margin is applying differently per each dish and so the buttons don't line-up.

I am failing to workout how to align the buttons using margin, but I know there must be a way using css to align them no matter the size of content but have not been able to find it.

is the button and I am currently just adjusting the css in the heading section of Material UI's styles to try and position the buttons.

[Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-curran-kn2op?file=/src/App.js)

Code Below:
Accordion.JS

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Accordion from '@material-ui/core/Accordion';
import AccordionSummary from '@material-ui/core/AccordionSummary';
import AccordionDetails from '@material-ui/core/AccordionDetails';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
import LaunchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Launch';

import MaterialIconButton from './IconButton'





const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
  },
  heading: {
    marginTop: "0.75rem",
    marginRight: "20%",
    fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(15),
    fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightRegular,
  },
}));

export default function PastaAccordion(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Accordion>
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls="panel1a-content"
          id={props.id}
        >
          <Typography className={classes.heading}>{props.title}</Typography>
          <MaterialIconButton/>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography>
            {props.description}
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
    </div>
  );
}
```

IconButton.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import NavigateNextIcon from '@material-ui/icons/NavigateNext';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    '& > *': {
    //   margin: theme.spacing(1),
     
    },
  },
}));

export default function MaterialIconButton() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <IconButton aria-label="delete">
        <NavigateNextIcon />
      </IconButton>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And in case you might need it this is where the accordion is rendered:

RecipeList.js

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components';
import PastaAccordion from '../Components/Accordion';
import BottomNav from '../Components/BottomNav';
import {PastaData, SoupData, StirFryData} from '../Data/RecipeData'
import handPinch from '../Assets/Hands Pinch.svg'


export const accordionCreator = (item) => {
    return(
      <PastaAccordion
        key={item.id}
        title={item.title}
        description={item.description}
      />
    )
  }

export const RecipeListPage = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Container>
                <TitleDiv>
                    Recipe List
                </TitleDiv>
                <Wrapper>
                    <PastaSubtitleDiv>
                        Pasta Dishes
                    </PastaSubtitleDiv>
                    <PastaAccordionDiv>
                        {PastaData.map(accordionCreator)}
                    </PastaAccordionDiv>
                    <StirFrySubtitleDiv>
                        Stir Fries
                    </StirFrySubtitleDiv>
                    <StirFryAccordionDiv>
                        {StirFryData.map(accordionCreator)}
                    </StirFryAccordionDiv>
                    <SoupSubtitleDiv>
                        Soups
                    </SoupSubtitleDiv>
                    <SoupAccordionDiv>
                        {SoupData.map(accordionCreator)}
                    </SoupAccordionDiv>
                </Wrapper>
                <BottomNav/>
            </Container>
        </div>
    )
}

const Container = styled.div`
position: relative;
display: flex;
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
/* background: #FDFAF6; */
/* background: #A6E3E9; */
/* background-image: linear-gradient(120deg, #A6E3E9, #f8eded); */
`

const Wrapper = styled.div`
position: absolute;
margin-top: 1.5rem;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;

`

const PastaAccordionDiv = styled.div`
    position: relative;
    top: 2%;
    
`
const StirFryAccordionDiv = styled.div`
    position: relative;
    top: 2%;
    
`
const SoupAccordionDiv = styled.div`
    position: relative;
    top: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 5rem;
    
`

const TitleDiv = styled.div`
    position: relative;
    top: 3%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
`

const PastaSubtitleDiv = styled.div`
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 4rem;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    
`
const StirFrySubtitleDiv = styled.div`
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 4rem;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
`
const SoupSubtitleDiv = styled.div`
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 4rem;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
`

const HandPinchImg = styled.div`
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    /* margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    vertical-align: middle; */
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    background-image: url(${handPinch});
`
```

Comment: Please make a [mcve], like a codesandbox

Comment: Trying to now will be up soon

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-curran-kn2op?file=/src/App.js

Comment: For reference I have been developing this on Iphone 8 mobile screen If  i remember correctly - this is a mobile only project

Comment: I'm not sure how you intend it to look, but you can try using some combination of CSS grid, `overflow`, and `text-overflow` on `AccordionSummary` and `classes.heading`.